# Putting together different images in a View / Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm parsing different image urls from a server and I want to combine them and display them inside a RecyclerView with a custom Adapter:

[image]

I'm using **JAVA+KOTLIN+GLIDE** to do that + to reduce traffic, the parsed images are saved as SVGs on the server. The custom Adapter isn't the problem, I'm stuck on how to parse and display the images inside the Adapter:
Is it economic to use another adapter inside the adapter or should I use a View inside the adapter? When using an adapter, how can I get the adapter to display 5 items / row?

I'm trying to display 5 elements / line with a maximum of 10 items (could be less sometimes) and the view/items should **NOT** be scrollable horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another recyclerview on on your adapter, I believe it will be the best way to make your solution dynamic.

Comment: How can I get the RcyclerView to put 5 items in each row?

Comment: You will create one recyclerview and on it is row create another recyclerview and make it horizontal in this case it will be dynamic.

Comment: isn't this possible with one recyclerview instead?

Comment: I think one recycler will be difficult.